# Apache james relaying denied

Tags: email, james

I was trying to send mail to my gmail id using apche james but i am getting this error

Requested action not taken: relaying denied

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is still relevant to you, you need to do further configuration in your config.xml, especially important would be to define a DNS server. and the relay-mailet.

On another (but important) note:

If you're trying to send to gmail from a dynamic IP (like most people have), gmail will probably deny your request on the grounds of you being a possible spammer.
A static IP-address is mostly needed for actions like this.

Comment: I am using a VPS in the cloud. Would Google consider that to be dynamic?

Comment: @Just1689 I'm not sure about that, but it might very well be. Maybe ask your VPS-provider about this?